# Rewrite rule to hide port from URL of Rails server?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rails server running on URL "http://example.com:1234"
I want to provide the URL of this application to an user as "http://example.com/myapp" so that Apache (or Rack or whatever you suggest that works) can redirect request for "/myapp" to port 3333 of that domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at setting up a [Reverse Proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) under apache.

Apache, listening to port 80 on example.com, would reverse proxy to port 1234. Then requests for http://example.com/myapp would be internally proxied to http://example.com:1234/myapp (or however you setup your ProxyPass target).

If you don't have access to server config, you can use mod_rewrite's Proxy flag and setup some rules inside an .htaccess file. Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^myapp(.*) http://example.com:1234/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Forgive me i am new to this but are there any security concern of using these ?

Comment: @KrunalLimbad There's always some concern when you have htaccess files (someone could possibly compromise something on the server or website and overwrite the htaccess file) but as long as you're not turning on the Proxy directive, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Somethimes it loose it css style. You can use only:

```
RewriteRule ^myapp(.*) http://example.com:1234 [L,R]
```