# How to hide my website port number?

Tags: url

I've been able to map www.xyz.com sub domain name to some ip port where port is not the default http port 80 but e.g. 1234

Entering www.xyz.com in browser works but resolves to www.xyz.com:1234

Please bear with me if my question sounds silly as am no expert of the networking domain.

Is that possible to keep port to non-default without it appearing with sub domain name in browser address bar?

Answer (score 3):

**Browser will show non-standard ports.** However there are some **workarounds** depending on your tech stack:

1. You can have a redirect from port 80 (or 443) to port 1234.

> For example in AWS you can have a Load Balancer that redirects traffic
>   from port 80 to 1234. The user in his browser will see no port.

2. You can  have a Reverse Proxy with a rewrite rule.

> Check here:
>   [Rewrite rule to hide port from URL of Rails server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330552/rewrite-rule-to-hide-port-from-url-of-rails-server)

Comment: reverse proxy - it's the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Browsers always show non-default port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to hide **"1234" port number** from your url.

Because:

- For **"http" url**, browser only hides **"80" port number**.
- For **"https" url**, browser only hides **"443" port number**.