# Docker and apache2, remove port from url

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

I'm working with `Docker` on an `Ubuntu server`, and I have an `Apache2` container.

This container is working, if I go to http://my-server-ip:8080,  I can see my folders and files in the folder `/var/www/html` of my Apache2 container.

`/var/www/html` in the container is linked with the folder `/home/me` on my machine. So I work directly in `/home/me`.

Now I need to add a VirtualHost for redirect a subdomain to a specific  folder `/var/www/html/portfolio`.

So I connect to my container and add a new host like :

```
<VirtualHosT *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portfolio
    ServerName my.subdomain.com
    ServerAlias my.subdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The result is when I go to `my.subdomain.com:8080` it's ok, I can read the content of `/var/www/html/portfolio`, but my question is :

How can I remove the :8080 in the URL ?

Comment: Have you checked:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23228/how-do-i-hide-the-port-in-my-url   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330552/rewrite-rule-to-hide-port-from-url-of-rails-server   also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155529/how-to-remove-port-number-from-http-localhost8123-to-use-as-http-localhost?

Comment: how is your container being run? do you have -p 8080:xxxx there?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Options:

1. `Publish` your container on `port 8`0, this requires docker host to have `port 80` as a free port.
2. Use another `nginx` on port 80 and `reverse prox`y to your apache container that runs on port 8080.